# Separation of variables in ODE with complex conjugate function

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following system:
$$\dot z = \bar z·e^{it}$$
$$z:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\qquad z(t_0) = z_0$$
I cannot figure out how to properly separate the right- and lefthandside. I tried:
$$\int\frac{z}{||z||^2}dz + C= -ie^{it}$$
but wasn't successful.

I will be glad about any tips.

Comment: Collect real and imaginary parts? Multiply both sides by $z$?

Comment: I would, if possible, keep the unknown function $z(t)$ as it is, rather than breaking it up into real and imaginary part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not gonna like this, but the answer is fairly convoluted. Divide both sides of the equation by $z$ and rewrite it in the form of $z = e^{\rho + i\phi}$:

$$\frac{\dot{z}}{z} = \frac{\bar{z}}{z}e^{it} \implies \dot{\rho} + i\dot{\phi} = e^{i(t-2\phi)}$$

where $\phi$ and $\rho$ are real functions. Take a look at the imaginary part only to get the ODE

$$\dot{\phi} = -\sin(2\phi - t) \implies \dot{\varphi}+1 = -2\sin\varphi$$

from the substitution $\varphi = 2\phi - t$. Then finagling around with trig identities allows us to integrate the separated variables.

$$-t+c = \int \frac{d\varphi}{1+2\sin\varphi} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sec^2 \frac{\varphi}{2}}{\tan \frac{\varphi}{2} + 2 - \sqrt{3}} - \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sec^2 \frac{\varphi}{2}}{\tan \frac{\varphi}{2} + 2 + \sqrt{3}}\:d\varphi$$

$$\implies \frac{\tan \frac{\varphi}{2} + 2 - \sqrt{3}}{\tan \frac{\varphi}{2} + 2 + \sqrt{3}} = Ce^{-\sqrt{3}t} \implies \varphi = 2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{1-Ce^{-\sqrt{3}t}}-(2+\sqrt{3})\right)$$

which means that

$$\phi = \frac{t}{2}+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{1-Ce^{-\sqrt{3}t}}-(2+\sqrt{3})\right)$$

Now we would have to plug this back into the real part of the equation and solve for $\rho$. Trig triangles are your friends. Good luck.

---

$\textbf{EDIT}$: If the unboundedness of the solution is all that is required, then this solution is very close. For ease of writing, denote

$$\phi = \frac{t}{2} + f(t) \implies \dot{\phi} = \frac{1}{2} + f'(t)$$

Instead of plugging back in to solve for $\rho$, the first equation in this post implies

$$ \dot{\rho}^2 + \dot{\phi}^2 = 1 \implies \dot{\rho^2} = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}+f'(t)\right)^2$$

Now take the limit as $t\to\infty$. Notice that $f(t)$ approaches $\tan^{-1}(2\sqrt{3} - (2+\sqrt{3})$ monotonically and smoothly. Thus $f'(t) \to 0$ which means we have that

$$\dot{\rho}^2 \to \frac{3}{4}$$

which means the magnitude $|z|$ will grow without bound.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears to me that there has to be an easier way. I'll add some more details to the general question.

Comment: @PabloJeken I would suggest accepting this answer and creating a new question with your added context, since I suspect it would invalidate a lot of this work.

Comment: Ok, I will do that then. Thanks for the effort. Is it ok if I leave the things I added or shall I remove them?

Comment: @PabloJeken this version has been edited with how to continue from here, but leave the other one up so you can get the intended answer.